# Key press 'enter' on web page does not work on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have javascript that handling key press enter trigger specific button event:

```
if (window.event)
    key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
else
    key = e.which;     //firefox

if (key == 13) {
//Get the button the user wants to have clicked
var btn = document.getElementById(buttonName);
if (btn != null) { //If we find the button click it
    btn.click();
    event.keyCode = 0
}
```

It's works on IE and Firefox, but not on Chrome. Any solutions?

Comment: `e.keyCode` for chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.keyCode` for chrome. Far as i know it also works in IE and Firefox

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried and does not work again,  with Chrome enter key trigger another button